# Java enum best practice

Tags: java, enums

This might seem like a trivial question, but I'm a bit muddled in my thinking regarding enums..

So I have a class - let's say its called DVDPlayer - and I want to have an enum that represents whether it's ON, OFF, or STANDBY.

So I can put the enum in the class - it doesn't make sense outside of the class. My question is this - should the enum be public, so that other classes can query values, or should I make it private, and then have "isOn", "isOFf" and "isStandby" methods?

The latter sounds a bit daft, but I'm unsure as to whether it's a good idea to have the enum as public as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say it seems like a good idea to make it public. Main reason being that the application is **easier to extend** since you wouldn't have to think about adding new methods each time you add a state.

If you decide to make it public, you should consider having it as top-level enum. I don't really see why you say *"it doesn't make sense outside of the class"*. I think a `DVDPlayerState` sounds like a perfectly fine public / top-level enum.

Comment: I just thought that the state shouldn't have a life of it's own aside from the DVDPlayer - it only has meaning with regards to the DVDPlayer.

Comment: At the same time, it might. You might have a DvdPlayerRemoteControl which is very interested in what states the DvdPlayer can have.

Comment: true. I've changed the example in oder to post it here, so I probably haven't thought it through that much!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you want to use the `DVDPlayer` class from the outside world:

```
if (dvdPlayer.getState() == State.ON)
```

or

```
if (dvdPlayer.isOn())
```

I think the first one is a better option. You don't have to pollute your code with delegating methods.

Comment: Actually I'd prefer the latter because isOn() reads a lot faster than wrapping your head around what could be meant by a state, for which you would first need to look up the enum.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb you want to keep things as private as possible (though usually, that's not the use case with enums), but from the way your question is posed, I'm not sure you're using enums as intended.

You want to use an enum to represent fixed values; it's cleaner alternative to saving these values as static final Integers or Strings. So for an enum declared as

```
public enum DvdState { ON, OFF, STANDBY };
```

Your class would look a bit like this:

```
public class DvdPlayer {
    private DvdState state = DvdState.OFF;

    public void setState(DvdState state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

And a calling class would use the following code:

```
dvdPlayer.setState(DvdState.ON);
```

Comment: This way of thinking feels much like over-engineering. I want to turn a player on or off. Nobody would ever say she wants to change or set the state of the player...

Answer (score 0):

Making the enum public could make sense. You would then have something like this:

```
DvdPlayer.State getState();
```

If you only have three states, it may be preferable to use the isOn, isOff, and isStandby methods. For more states the public enum is better. Also an enum can be used in a switch statement, which is convenient.

Answer (score 0):

If the `enum` is part of the public interface, it makes sense to declare it **public**. That seems to be the case with the **DVPlayer**, because you say it can be queried. The three methods "**isOn**", "**isOFf**" and "**isStandby**" unnecessarily bloat the public interface.

But there are times when an `enum` comes in handy for use within the class, in which case it should be declared **private**. For example, the following declaration

```
private enum Format{DVD, BLURAY};
```

would be okay, if *Format* is used internally in the **DVDPlayer** class but is not part of the public interface either as a parameter or return value of a method.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm gonna be the first one to advocate the use of methods here. First, think about the users of your class. The less they need to know about your business domain, the better, so don't confuse them with things like "state". You wouldn't "set the state" of a DVD player in real life, but just "turn it on" or "turn if off", which to me screams for methods. Aside from that Java is known and loved for being strictly statically typed, which allows you to discover an interface solely by the auto-complete suggestions of your IDE. Reading a method `turnOff` makes sense instantly to me, while a `setState` is ambiguous and would require me to look up the state enum first in order for me to know what the state actually can be.